# vImage from UIImage or from file - Swift and Accelerate framework

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework

I would like to know how to instantiate a vImage object in Swift, either from a file or from another image container object (`UIImage`, `CGImage`). The Apple documentation on the subject seems sparse and a bit confusing. It seems like it simply needs a basic data structure pointer (a bit like the `data` `uchar*` variable of the `cv::Mat` structure in OpenCV), though I am not sure how to obtain this in Swift.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See vImageBuffer_initWithCGImage()

Some translation to swift may be required.